# error: expected nested-name-specifier when compile breakpad android sample app

Tags: android-ndk

When I try to compile android sample app of breakpad, I got this error and have no idea how to resolve it. I'm using Mac OSX 10.11 and android ndk r10e. Many Thanks in advance.

```
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:47:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc'
 using AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc = int (*)(int bufID, int prio, const char *tag,
   ^
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:53:1: error: 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc' does not name a type
 AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc g_android_log_buf_write = nullptr;
 ^
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc: In function 'void logger::initializeCrashLogWriter()':
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:3: error: 'g_android_log_buf_write' was not declared in this scope
   g_android_log_buf_write = reinterpret_cast<AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc>(
   ^
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:46: error: 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc' does not name a type
   g_android_log_buf_write = reinterpret_cast<AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc>(
                                          ^
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc: In function 'int logger::writeToCrashLog(const char*)':
jni/../../google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:68:7: error: 'g_android_log_buf_write' was not declared in this scope
   if (g_android_log_buf_write) {
```